# SQL Query - Time in State

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to wrap my head around a sql query that I need to develop.  I need to calculate the percentage of time a sensor has been above a limit over a defined time period.

The data in my table looks something like this:

```
Id,          TimeStamp,  Value,    SensorName 
1,  2018-03-16 00:00:01,    45,  Temperature1 
2,  2018-03-16 00:00:01,    53,  Temperature2    
3,  2018-03-16 00:00:02,    46,  Temperature1    
4,  2018-03-16 00:00:02,    54,  Temperature2    
4,  2018-03-16 00:00:03,    45,  Temperature1    
5,  2018-03-16 00:00:04,    46,  Temperature1    
6,  2018-03-16 00:00:05,    45,  Temperature2
```

..........

Each sensor typically has one record every second, though there could be less records if the sensor value does not change.

How could I write a query that shows me the percentage of time Temperature1 was greater than 45 over the last hour?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your attempts in cracking this and we will help you with the issue you are facing. You can definitely do this with aggregate functions.

Comment: Break it into small steps.   All of the coding is easy if you think of it in small steps.

Comment: Does your ID column allow duplicates? Or is that a typo?  (two 4s)

Comment: As phrased, the question is so ambiguous as to be too broad.  How is the excess period determined?  How is the "last hour" defined -- based on the clock or the most recent reading?  What if there are no observations during the hour?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compute the moving average over the last n hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706012/how-to-compute-the-moving-average-over-the-last-n-hours)

Answer (score 0):

replace @temp with your table name

```
select (cast(e.exceed as float)/cast(t.tot as float)) * 100.00 as [% exceed] from
(
select count(*) exceed
from @temp
where
SensorName = 'temperature1'
and TimeStamp between '2018-03-16 00:00:01' and '2018-03-16 00:00:02'
and Value > 45) e,

(
select count(*) tot
from @temp
where
SensorName = 'temperature1'
and TimeStamp between '2018-03-16 00:00:01' and '2018-03-16 00:00:02'
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM with a conditional value:

```
Declare @t table (Id int,[TimeStamp] datetime, [Value] int, SensorName nvarchar(30))
insert into @t values
  (1,'2018-03-16 00:00:01',45,'Temperature1')
, (2,'2018-03-16 00:00:01',53,'Temperature2')
, (3,'2018-03-16 00:00:02',46,'Temperature1')
, (4,'2018-03-16 00:00:02',54,'Temperature2')
, (4,'2018-03-16 00:00:03',45,'Temperature1')
, (5,'2018-03-16 00:00:04',46,'Temperature1')
, (6,'2018-03-16 00:00:05',45,'Temperature2')

Declare @tempvalue int = 45

select sum(iif([Value]>@tempvalue,1.0,0.0))/count(*)*100
from @t
where SensorName = 'Temperature1'
```